# TomTom POIs search API is returning random total results (between 90 to 100) for same input

Tags: api, tomtom

I am trying to use TomTom POIs search API and I am getting a total amount of results that doesn't match the reality... also it looks like for the same input a random total between 90 to 100 is returned.

Is there anything that am I doing wrong?

The request I am doing is this one: [https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/poiSearch/Firestone%20Complete%20Auto%20Care.json?countrySet=US&view=Unified&relatedPois=all&key=[API_KEY]&offset=10](https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/poiSearch/Firestone%20Complete%20Auto%20Care.json?countrySet=US&view=Unified&relatedPois=all&key=%5BAPI_KEY%5D&offset=10)

Also here you can find the documentation: https://developer.tomtom.com/search-api/documentation/search-service/points-of-interest-search

Thanks in advance!

My expectation is to get the real and consistent amount of locations base on the input params.
For the example above, at least 1000 should be returned.